# Simple HTML include system (Nested includes)

Tags: php, html

My html files are becoming very huge as I'm writing a big html app and I want to organised it. I have an array that will include all the includes that looks like this:

```
$html_includes = [
  'menu',
  'tools',
  'canvas',
  'sidebar' => [
    "resource",
    "layers"
  ],
  "footer"
];
```

What I'm trying to do is create an function to include all the files and if there's a folder (e.g. sidebar) include `<folder>.html` and create a callback to include the files withing the `<folder>.html` file. Here my attempt so far:

```
function include_html($includes,$path=""){
    foreach($includes as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            function callback(){
                include_html($value,($path.$key."/"));
            }
        } 
        include($path.$key.".html");
    }
}

include_html($html_includes);
```

---

*Folder structure*

```
\canvas.html
\menu.html
\tools.html
\sidebar
\sidebar\layers.html
\sidebar\resources.html
\sidebar\sidebar.html
```

*sidebar.html*

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="sortable">
        <?php callback(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Scope is the problem as callback doest not have access to `$value/$key`. What I maybe need maybe is Anonymous functions but I'm not sure if that's correct. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Copy paste your pages to Wordpress or Drupal and do something fun with the time you saved by doing that! :)

Comment: Really, i love drupal! and it includes same kind of feature that your are trying to code. Learn drupal instead. That's my opinion..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the figured out function that I needed, using http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

```
function include_html($includes, $path = "") {
  foreach($includes as $key = > $value) {
      if (is_array($value)) {
          $callback = function () use($value, $key, $path) {
              include_html($value, ($path.$key."/"));
          };
          include $path.$key."/".$key.".html";
      } else include $path.$value.".html";
  }
}

include_html($html_includes, $html_path);
```

In `sidebar.html` changed from `callback() -> $callback()`

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a good way to organised code?

Short Answer: No.

You're maintaining a folder structure with all of your includes, and then you're maintaining a second system of arrays to manage it all. If your site grows any larger or more complex it's quickly going to become unmaintainable.

At the very least you should change all of these files to `.php` or set up your server to run `.html` files through the PHP interpreter. Then when one file needs to include another you can simply `<?php include('otherfile.php'); ?>` and everything that *that* file needs will be included, and so on down the chain without having to keep track of the structure separately.

This could probably also be accomplished with Server Side Includes, but IMHO that's something best avoided.

That said, constructing your site like this is only marginally better than static HTML files. You should definitely look into using some sort of framework.

Comment: It's not a site, its just one single html file all the separate files are just snippets of code. I don't need `.php` extension as its just plain html and having one html files with 900 lines of code is messy. A php framework i don't think would fit my project as its intended for multiple page setup